# What is better: A) loop through strategy.closedtrades or B) collect data at each bar in arrays?

Tags: statistics

I would like to stratify profit by weekday and trade direction. Which of the following approaches is more efficient?

A) loop through strategy.closedtrades at barstate.islastconfirmedhistory

B) have a matrix collect all the data at each new bar at change(strategy.closedtrades)

Laura

What is the best way to store the information? I tried:

a) having a user defined type but I could not store arrays in fields

b) having multiple arrays but it was tedious to declare and update them all

c) having a matrix declared only once but it could only store one data type

Comment: Please (re-)read [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).